# Listen fifo and socket files

Tags: linux, unix, posix

I have two process, which speak with fifo or socket file. Can I somehow read the information they are exchanging? If some of information crashes, I don't care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow? Of course, somehow. Write a kernel device driver. Or, for a really big challenge, open /dev/mem and figure out where the information happens to be :-)

You'll need to be more specific in terms to get a more useful answer. Do you have root access? Are you willing to leave traces? Are you willing to attach ptrace/strace to one of them?

Comment: In fact this is only theoretical question. So I have root access and can do everything I want. Reading /dev/mem is a good idea - thanks. Ptrace works only if I know which app is working with this file, doesn't it?

Comment: @Xim you wrote, 'I have two processes'. So I wrote: 'attach strace or ptrace to one.' strace is particularly apt. If you don't 'have' the processes, then kernel code or trolling /dev/mem is your ticket.